# Access rights icons for web site

Tags: icons

I have a customer with a search page for videos that displays filters to the left (elastic search aggregations).

Each of these filters are tags applied to different videos. When a user makes a search, the results page "builds" these filters which can fall into any of the following categories:

- Full access – Public videos and purchased videos only: the given filter only contains videos that anyone can watch or that a given customer has purchased (no padlock)
- Partial access – Purchased videos and non-purchased videos only: this filter contains videos that a customer has purchased AND videos that need to be purchased to watch them. (faded padlock)
- No access – Videos that can be purchased: this category ONLY contains videos that the user has not purchased. (black padlock)

OK. The way this thing works does not make much sense to me, but we apparently cannot change that.

Now, the way access rights are displayed (using padlocks) is, in my opinion, very confusing but we cannot think about another way to implement it – specially the faded ones.

Could anyone please help me get some ideas/guidance about what iconography for access rights can be applied here?

[image]

Comment: As it is, your question is about icon suggestion and such questions are off-topic. This is an interesting question but you should rewrite so that it asks about possible ways to differentiate between access rights, not just icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that categories are independent of the user rights on the videos (for example, categories are thematic, and for any category, any level of rights can apply).

I agree with you that associating a padlock to the filters doesn't make sense, as the categories / filters themselves are not restricted, only some of the contents within each category. A user can always click on a category name even with a black padlock and see the list of videos it contains.

This functionality looks more like a paywall to me: I would suggest to use a currency symbol instead of a padlock. It would make clear to the user that there is a cost involved to access some resources. A padlock could give the idea that some resources are not accessible at all.

I would also place the icon next to the number of documents on the right, rather than before the category.
You mention that no change is possible unfortunately, but, ideally, I would have 3 different icons (public, purchased, to-be-purchased) and state the number of documents of each type in each category.

Answer (score 1):

How about the "Dollar" symbol?
Use $ for not purchased videos, $ with a check mark for purchased videos and for free videos a strikethrough $.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, a dollar sign would actually make more sense. We'll experiment  with the concept.